# VirtualBox on Ubuntu 14.04 to run an existing Windows 7 Install

Tags: virtualbox, system-installation

Ok...
Here's what I am looking to do.  I have completely fallen head over heels in love with Linux over the last few years... however, being a developer I have always needed to have my development/coding machine be a windows box.

So I can have Visual Studio, Office, SQL Server, etc installed for my development processes.

I really want to convert this machine into a Ubuntu Desktop... like... badly.

So, my real question to the community is: can I take a snapshot of my current windows install, and convert it to a Virtual Machine for use in VirtualBox once I get Ubuntu installed, and how?

And because... I don't want to have to re-install all my windows software from scratch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the following link  , I think it may help you solving your issue

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows

and this is a workaround you may make use of it

http://www.sysprobs.com/physical-virtual-virtualbox-virtualbox-p2v

Comment: thanks.  Gonna take awhile.   I think disk2vhd doesn't like compressed drives (where I was going to store the image).  I tried creating a VHD in windows management interface, and that failed stating can't on compressed disks... so after a few hours, and a few failures, just now waiting on the drive uncompressing LOL